# security block self-running java program

Tags: security, java

I'm running a java program, but it is blocked by security software(maybe McAfee),

I got a pop-up which says: Application Blocked by Security settings

your security settings have blocked a self-signed application from running

Name: oracle.forms.engine.Main
Location: https://sid.studenti.polito.it
Reason:your security settings have blocked a self-signed application from running

the errors are:

```
Java Plug-in 10.51.2.13
Using JRE version 1.7.0_51-b13 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
User home directory = C:\Users\user
----------------------------------------------------
c:   clear console window
f:   finalize objects on finalization queue
g:   garbage collect
h:   display this help message
l:   dump classloader list
m:   print memory usage
o:   trigger logging
q:   hide console
r:   reload policy configuration
s:   dump system and deployment properties
t:   dump thread list
v:   dump thread stack
x:   clear classloader cache
0-5: set trace level to <n>
----------------------------------------------------

    com.sun.deploy.security.BlockedException: Your security settings have blocked a self-signed application from running
at com.sun.deploy.security.SandboxSecurity.showBlockedDialog(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.TrustDecider.askUser(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.TrustDecider.validateChain(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.TrustDecider.isAllPermissionGranted(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.isTrustedByTrustDecider(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.getTrustedCodeSources(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.CPCallbackHandler$ParentCallback.strategy(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.CPCallbackHandler$ParentCallback.openClassPathElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.getJarFile(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.access$1000(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.ensureOpen(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath.getLoader(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath.getLoader(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath.getResource(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.findClassHelper(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.initAppletAdapter(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

how to deal with this?
thanks

Comment: You could always turn of your security to confirm it's blocker. Add a security exception to the program to let it through. Your "error" doesn't tell us anything.

Comment: how do you know its being blocked if you don't know for sure what program is doing it?

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21157450/how-to-make-a-machine-trust-a-self-signed-java-application

Answer (score 3):

The applet is being blocked by Java itself, because after java 7U51, Self Signed packages do not execute  by default per the new security configuration.

> An application with self-signed certificate is blocked by default. Applications of this type present the highest level of risk because publisher is not identified and the application may be granted access to personal data on your computer.

from: https://www.java.com/en/download/help/java_blocked.xml

The best way to deal with the problem is to fix the program itself, following the [best practices documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/).

if you are not the author, you can create an exception in your java runtime:

Open the java Control Panel -> Security -> Edit Site List
 and Add the URL to the applet, and its parent web page.

See more info at: https://www.java.com/en/download/help/java_blocked.xml